# Internal Server Error(500) paypal create payment Rest API with Java json payload in Sandbox

Tags: java, json, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting an **Internal Server Error(500)** when creating a paypal payment with Java code using json payload in Sandbox.

I made this with json:

```
{
"intent": "sale",
"redirect_urls":
{
"return_url": "somelink",
"cancel_url": "somelink"
},
"payer":
{
"payment_method": "paypal"
},
"transactions": [
{
"amount":
{
"total": "17",
"currency": "EUR"
},
"description": "This is payment tran."
}]
}
```

I tried to complete the same stuff using postman and I can do that. In fact I completed the whole payment transaction(approval and execution) using postman

I am passing proper access token with Bearer.

```
HttpPost paymentPost = new HttpPost("api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"); 
paymentPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, pt.getTokenType() + " " + pt.getAccessToken()); 
List<NameValuePair> nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4); 
nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content-type", "application/json")); nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json"));
paymentPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));
```

Comment: Did you set the proper content type header. Content-Type:application/json?

Comment: Hi Nitish I am using below code   
  HttpPost paymentPost = new HttpPost("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
  paymentPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, pt.getTokenType() + " " + pt.getAccessToken());
  
  List<NameValuePair> nvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
  nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content-type", "application/json"));
  nvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Accept", "application/json"));
  paymentPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPairs));

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the content type and Accept to body of the request and not to headers. And also in your code i don't see where you are adding the json to the request. Maybe you are doing that and have not shown it in your code you posted. . You need to use addHeader for adding both the headers. Maybe you can try the below code and see if it fixes the issue.

```
HttpPost paymentPost = new HttpPost("api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
paymentPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, pt.getTokenType() + " " + pt.getAccessToken());  
paymentPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json"); 
paymentPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
paymentPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(/**"YOUR JSON STRING"**/));
```

Comment: Thanks Nithish. I missed that. I am constructing and passing my json in String entity.

Comment: Yes Nitish. Sorry for so late reply.